# Firefox: Prevent middle-click on tab-bar from creating new tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, css

In Firefox v. 76, how can one prevent a middle=mouse click on the tab bar from opening a new, empty, tab? In older versions, though there was no *about:config* entry to control that behavior, it was possible to prevent it using [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/) with the following code:

```
/* Disable New Tab on MiddleClick */
#tabbrowser-tabs .arrowscrollbox-scrollbox{pointer-events: none} .tabbrowser-tab,.tabs-newtab-button{pointer-events: auto}
```

This no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Loathe as I am to answer my own question, after doing considerable research and experimantation, I found the following works. **N.B.** TabsToolbar seems to be case-sensitive.

```
/* Disable New Tab on MiddleClick */
#tabbrowser-tabs .arrowscrollbox-scrollbox{pointer-events: none} .tabbrowser-tab,.tabs-newtab-button{pointer-events: auto}
#TabsToolbar .toolbar-items {pointer-events: none}
```

Comment: @harrymc, thanks for notifying me. However, though I added a fragment of an answer, it suppresses *all* click events.  BTW, if you or anyone knows of documentation for the Mozilla userChrome.css, please let me know -- I can find little online.